# add background to 3 level accordion menu

Tags: jquery, menu, jquery-ui-accordion

I want to add background to active menu.

so if I click first level I get the background, but when I click on second level the first level background is hide and I want to keep this show up.

Here is my code

```
$('.sidenav li:has(ul)').addClass("has-sub");
$('.sidenav').find('.has-sub').find('a:first').addClass("sub");
$('.sidenav ul ul').addClass("sub-menu");
$(".sub-menu").hide();

$('.sidenav li a').click( function() {
    var checkElement = $(this).next(); 

    $('.sidenav li').removeClass('active');
    $(this).closest('li').addClass('active'); 

    if ((checkElement.is('ul')) && (checkElement.is(':visible'))) {
        $(this).closest('li').removeClass('active');
        checkElement.slideUp('normal');
        return false;
    }

    if ((checkElement.is('ul')) && (!checkElement.is(':visible'))) {
        $('.sidenav ul:visible').not(checkElement.parentsUntil('.sidenav')).slideUp('normal');
        checkElement.slideDown('normal');
        return false;
    }
});
```

and here is link to [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ru7ge/1/)

maybe someone can help. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add this :

```
$(this).parentsUntil(".sidenav").addClass('active');
```

instead of

```
$(this).closest('li').addClass('active');
```

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/ru7ge/7/)

Comment: This will add class active to all parents, including nav, and body and other wrappers

Comment: Yeah, will go back to previous answer.

Comment: have you tried this out? http://jsfiddle.net/ru7ge/6/ if you click on the most inner child it will remove the red from the highest li

Comment: Just comparing our Fiddle and didn't see difference

Comment: Click 'research units' > click 'research news and event' > click any of the children, besides that your code also adds active to 3 parents up from whatever item the user clicked on

Answer (score 0):

You can check which item you are clicking on

```
if( $(this).parent().hasClass('top') ) {
    $('.sidenav li').removeClass('active');
} else {
    $('.sidenav li:not(.top)').removeClass('active');
}
```

and added the top class to the top level items

```
<li class="top"><a href="#">Research Units</a>....
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ru7ge/5/